# Set up a wiki in watch mode with Hugo static site generator?

Tags: web-development, static-content, wiki

In the midst of porting an all HTML site to the [Hugo static site generator](http://gohugo.io/), my boss asked me to add a wiki to the site. The turn around time on this port + addition of a wiki is somewhat short (about a week), IMO. This is exaperated because I'm new to Hugo, and also I've never set up a wiki site, thus I have no knowledge about what wiki(s) might work with Hugo ... or even if this is something that can be accomplished within this much time.

Is this something that can be accomplished? If so, what wiki(s) would work with Hugo?

Edit for clarification: The wiki would enable users to edit content. Accounts would be (probably be) required. Editors would make their changes via a web interface, not via Hugo. Hugo would (I believe) be run in watch mode so that wiki edits would be updated (almost) immediately.

Comment: I do not know Hugo or do I work with Wikis. I roll my own. However, I did poke around a bit for an answer and did not see anything to grab hold of. Sorry. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't make accounts with Hugo. Hugo just generates static webpages from your [frontmatter](https://gohugo.io/content/front-matter/) and markdown details. It parses template style to specific layout that you have provided in your frontmatter.

You can create a wiki (By creating own wiki style) with Hugo but you can't make accounts for login and signup. It is not a CMS that saves login databases, as it doesn't use databases. But if you [host your Hugo website in github pages](https://gohugo.io/tutorials/github-pages-blog/), then you can allow other people to fork your github project, and later you decide weather you allow them to commit that changes or not. I don't see any other option for you.

Comment: There are other methods (server software based) of creating and managing web site accounts.

Comment: Hugo does not provide any kind of database facilities to store and validate authentication. It is static site generator. Github pages and other server side technologies might help, but Hugo does not offer those functionalities directly.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and you're repeating what you said in your answer. I was pointing out that there are other means of creating accounts for your website if that's what you need.

Comment: Great. I think you're new into Hugo, Hope you will create your own way with other methods :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like from your edit that you have come across the way to achieve this. I haven't used Hugo specifically, but having used other static site generators one way I have achieved this is to have a dynamic web portal which handled user access permissions and provided access to a series of base documents (markdown files in my case) for editing wiki articles and creating new articles. As each markdown file was changed or created the static site generator was set to regenerate the parts of the site that needed to be generated and performed well. To ensure that everyone didn't need access to the web portal I powered things like comments etc through social media plugins and so the only people who needed access to the portal where people who where approved to create and edit wiki articles for the site (which in the projects case was a small number of users affiliated with the organisation).